# Alternative proof for Fredholm's alternative

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove the following variant of Fredholm's alternative:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, $T \in GL(X)$ (invertible) and $A \in K(X)$
> (compact operator). Prove that $T+A$ is invertible iff $T+A$ is
> injective.

The invertible $\implies$ injective is immediate, but the other direction I am quite stuck on. I thought of using the regular form of Fredholm's alternative to prove this, but was unsuccessful. I then thought of using the same steps used in the actual proof for the original Fredholm's theorem, with some alterations, but that would be like a repeat of the original proof which seems redundant.

Is there a simpler way I am missing? (note - I am at an elementary level in Functional Analysis, so preferably this wouldn't require any advanced theorems).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the following standard form of the Fredholm Alternative

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, $I$ the identity operator, $\lambda$
> a complex number, and $A_0 \in K(X)$
> (a compact operator). If $A_0-\lambda I$ is injective,
> then $A_0-\lambda I$ is   invertible.

A good source for this is [1], see also [2].

Now let $X$ be a Banach space, $T \in GL(X)$ (invertible) and $A \in K(X)$.

Suppose that $T+A$ is injective. Then $T^{-1}\circ(T+A)=I+T^{-1}\circ A$ is also injective, and $A_0:=T^{-1}\circ A \in K(X)$. By the Fredholm Alternative with $\lambda=-1$, the operator $I+A_0$ is invertible, so
$T\circ(I+A_0)=T+A$ is also invertible.

[1] [https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/fredholm-riesz.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/fun/fredholm-riesz.pdf)

[2]   W. Arveson, A short course on spectral theory, Springer, 2002

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\codim}{\operatorname{codim}}\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$Under the given conditions, it is known that $T+A$ is Fredholm of index $0$, that is, $\dim\ker(T+A)=\codim\im(T+A)$. Suppose $T+A$ is injective: then $\dim\ker(T+A)=0$ hence $\codim\im(T+A)=0$. That is, $\im(T+A)=X$ and $T+A$ thus bijects.

Whether or not this counts as simple depends on whether or not you know this theorem. If you don't, you can find it on page 332 of [this](https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf) text and I will try to explain it.

Essentially, $T+A=T\circ[\mathrm{Id}+T^{-1}\circ A]$ and $T^{-1}\circ A\in\mathcal{K}(X)$ (why?). By Riesz-Schauder, $\mathrm{Id}+T^{-1}\circ A$ is then Fredholm-$0$, and the composition of it with an invertible operator ($T$) is also Fredholm-$0$ (the book leaves this as an exercise, but I have done this exercise and will demonstrate it if you wish). So, we have shown that $T+A$ is Fredholm-$0$.